# Declaring vars from scanner isn't working

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I don't know if something is up with my code, but my vars are not what I expect.

```
        dim = in.nextInt();

        row_req = new int[dim];
        col_req = new int[dim];
        camp = new char[dim][dim];

        for (int i = 0; i != dim; i++) {
            row_req[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i != dim; i++) {
            col_req[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
```

reads

3
1 0 1
0 2 0

as dim = 3, row_rew = [1, 0, 2], col_req = [0, 1, 0]

when I expect

dim = 3, row_rew = [1, 0, 1], col_req = [0, 2, 0]

Comment: It seems to be working for me. Could you include how you print the array out?

Comment: When I say, what the input is being read as, I mean these are the values the var has when examining in the debugger.

Comment: Best practice for for-loop is i < dim, not i != dim, believe it's not the problem here but anyone looking at your code should question it.

Answer (score 0):

Might be better and easier to debug if you put it right into a two-dimensional array.

```
dim = in.nextInt();
int[][] matrix = new int[dim][dim];
for (int r = 0; r < dim; r++) {
  for (int c = 0; c < dim; c++) {
    matrix[r][c] = in.nextInt();
  }
}
```

Also, it looks like you're ultimately populating a matrix of chars, aside from the dimension why not just read everything as chars in the first place, avoid temporary storage and unnecessary conversions.